# Search for string in one column and extract all the column for matched row Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to search for a string in one column and I want to extract whole dataframe when string matches in the column

My Data is as follows

```
**string**  **Number**
hello there     11
Hello hi        22
How are you     33
```

My code is as follows

```
string_hello = []
for i in df['string']:
    if re.search("Hello",i, flags=re.I): 
        string_hello.append(i)
```

Expected result is

```
**string**  **Number**
hello there     11
Hello hi        22
```

But My code only gives string column, how can I extract number column too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and perform boolean indexing on the dataframe with the result:

```
df[df.string.str.lower().str.contains(r'hello')]

      string    Number
0  hello there      11
1     Hello hi      22
```